# when i update two entities in postman i have null in laravel api

Tags: laravel, api, postman

**when i  update two  entities in  postman i have  null  in laravel api  and
I have two entities one is for employees and the other is for personalDetails

**this is my model employee:**

```
class Employee extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use HasFactory, InteractsWithMedia;

    protected  $guarded = [];

    protected $casts = [
        
    ];

public function personalDetails()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(PersonalDetails::class,'employee_id');
    }
```

**and this  is the personalDetails model**

```
class PersonalDetails extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use HasFactory, InteractsWithMedia;
    protected  $guarded = [];
    protected $casts = [
        'Date_of_birth'   => 'date',
        'joining_Date'     => 'date',
    ];

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class,'employee_id');
    }
```

**the controller is :**

```
public function update(UpdateEmployeeRequest $request,Employee $employee)
{
    $employee->update($request->validated());

    return new EmployeeResource($employee);
```

the rout:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->post('employee', [EmployeeController::class, 'store']);
```

**and the UpdateEmployeeRequest is :**

```
class UpdateEmployeeRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'Name_kanji'                        => ['required'],
            'Name_katakana'                     => ['required'],
            'Name_family_kanji'                 => ['required'],
            'Name_family_katakana'              => ['required'],
            'employee_number'                   => ['required','numeric'],
            'image'                             => ['required'],
            'Employee_state'                    => ['required', Rule::in([EmployeeState::Employed, EmployeeState::OnLeave, EmployeeState::Resigned])],
            'Employee_type'                     => ['required', Rule::in([EmployeeType::FullTime, EmployeeType::PartTime, EmployeeType::Director])],
            'Department'                        => ['required', Rule::in([Department::Design, Department::Management, Department::Sales])],
            'gender'                            => ['required', Rule::in([gender::male, gender::female])],
            'Current_age'                       => ['required'],
            'Company_day_based_age'             => ['required'],
            'jop_title'                         => ['required'],
            'Daily_travel_expenses'             => ['required'],
            'office'                            => ['required'],
            'Years_of_service'                  => ['required'],
            'Email_address'                     => ['required'],
            'My_number'                         => ['required','numeric'],
            'address_id'                        => ['required'],
            'domicile'                          => ['required'],
            'Contact_number'                    => ['required'],
            'Emergency_contact'                 => ['required'],
            'Emergency_contact_relation'        => ['required'],
            'Need_work_Instruction'             => ['required'],
            'Date_of_birth*'                    => ['required|array'],
                'Date_of_birth.*day'                => ['required'],
                'Date_of_birth.*year'               => ['required'],
                'Date_of_birth.*month'              => ['required'],
            'joining_Date*'                    => ['required|array'],
                'joining_Date.*day'                => ['required'],
                'joining_Date.*year'               => ['required'],
                'joining_Date.*month'              => ['required'],


        ];
    }

    public function validated($key = null, $default = null)
    {
        return [
           
                'Name_kanji'                        => $this->Name_kanji,
                'Name_katakana'                     => $this->Name_katakana,
                'Name_family_katakana'              => $this->Name_family_katakana,
                'Name_family_kanji'                 => $this->Name_family_kanji,
                'employee_number'                   => $this->employee_number,
                'image'                             => $this->image,
                'Employee_state'                    => $this->Employee_state,
                'Employee_type'                     => $this->Employee_type,
                'Department'                        => $this->Department,
                'gender'                            => $this->gender,
                'Current_age'                       => $this->Current_age,
                'Company_day_based_age'             => $this->Company_day_based_age,
                'jop_title'                         => $this->jop_title,
                'Daily_travel_expenses'             => $this->Daily_travel_expenses,
                'office'                            => $this->office,
                'Years_of_service'                  => $this->Years_of_service,
                'Email_address'                     => $this->Email_address,
                'My_number'                         => $this->My_number,
                'address_id'                        => $this->address_id,
                'domicile'                          => $this->domicile,
                'Contact_number'                    => $this->Contact_number,
                'Emergency_contact'                 => $this->Emergency_contact,
                'Emergency_contact_relation'        => $this->Emergency_contact_relation,
                'Need_work_Instruction'             => $this->Need_work_Instruction,
                'Date_of_birth'                     => Carbon::create(
                    $this->Date_of_birth['year'],
                    $this->Date_of_birth['month'],
                    $this->Date_of_birth['day'])->format('Y-m-d'),
                    
                'joining_Date'                     => Carbon::create(
                    $this->joining_Date['year'],
                    $this->joining_Date['month'],
                    $this->joining_Date['day'])->format('Y-m-d'),
            
        ];
    }
}
```

> **and the EmployeeResource:**

class EmployeeResource extends JsonResource
{

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return
    [       'id'                                => $this->id,
            'Name_kanji'                        => $this->Name_kanji,
            'Name_katakana'                     => $this->Name_katakana,
            'Name_family_kanji'                 => $this->Name_family_kanji,
            'Name_family_katakana'              => $this->Name_family_katakana,
            'employee_number'                   => $this->employee_number,
            'image'                             => $this->personalDetails?->getFirstMediaUrl('PersonalDetails'),
            'Employee_state'                    => $this->personalDetails?->Employee_state,
            'My_number'                         => $this->personalDetails?->My_number,
            'Employee_type'                     => $this->personalDetails?->Employee_type,
            'Daily_travel_expenses'             => $this->personalDetails?->Daily_travel_expenses,
            'Current_age'                       => $this->personalDetails?->Current_age,
            'Company_day_based_age'             => $this->personalDetails?->Company_day_based_age,
            'department'                        => $this->personalDetails?->department,
            'office'                            => $this->personalDetails?->office,
            'Gender'                            => $this->personalDetails?->Gender,
            'Date_of_birth'                        =>[
              'month'  =>  $this->personalDetails?->Date_of_birth->month,
              'day'  =>   $this->personalDetails?->Date_of_birth->day,
              'year'  =>    $this->personalDetails?->Date_of_birth->year,
            ],
            'joining_Date'                        =>[
                  'month'  =>  $this->personalDetails?->joining_Date->month,
                  'day'  =>   $this->personalDetails?->joining_Date->day,
                  'year'  =>    $this->personalDetails?->joining_Date->year,
                ],
            'Years_of_service'                  => $this->personalDetails?->Years_of_service,
            'Email_address'                     => $this->personalDetails?->Email_address,
            'address_id'                        => $this->personalDetails?->address_id,
            'jop_title'                         => $this->personalDetails?->jop_title,
            'domicile'                          => $this->personalDetails?->domicile,
            'Contact_number'                    => $this->personalDetails?->Contact_number,
            'Emergency_contact'                 => $this->personalDetails?->Emergency_contact,
            'Emergency_contact_relation'        => $this->personalDetails?->Emergency_contact_relation,
            'Need_work_Instruction'             => $this->personalDetails?->Need_work_Instruction,
```

**and When I run the code in postman it shows empty values ​​and it doesn't store what's the problem with that**

[image]

Comment: please do not put up pictures of code, code is text and belongs in a text block in your question .... is there a reason to redefine the `validated` method?

Answer (score 0):

You have no route parameter named `employee`. When you type-hint a variable on your route action (Controller method signature in this case) you are getting Dependency injection, not Implicit Route Model Binding; there is no parameter to bind. You are getting an empty `Employee` model instance. This instance has no attributes so you are getting `null`s for all the attributes you are trying to access.

The call to `update` is instantly just returning since the Model instance is non-existing.

What you have is the functional equivalent of this:

```
return new EmployeeResource(new Employee());
```

You would have to have a route parameter defined on your route and be passing some identifier for this parameter in the URL you are sending the request to:

```
Route::post('employee/{employee}', ...);

http://yoursite.com/employee/1
```